# How to make a pie chart with row data in Excel with Openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

`Hello, I am trying to make a pie chart wit row data using openpyxl. I have found several examples with column data but I need row data. The example is this one:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import (
    PieChart,
    ProjectedPieChart,
    Reference
)
from openpyxl.chart.series import DataPoint

data = [
    ['Pie', 'Apple', 'Cherry', 'Pumpkin', 'Chocolate'],
    ['Sold', 50, 30, 10 ,40]
    
]

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for row in data:
    ws.append(row)

pie = PieChart()
labels = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=5, max_row=1)
data = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_col=5, max_row=2)
pie.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
pie.set_categories(labels)
pie.title = "Pies sold by category"
ws.add_chart(pie, "D1")
```

#The result that I obtain is shown in the picture.[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKcRO.png)

#I have tried to modify the min_row/col and max_row/col but I do not manage to get the solution.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple form add the data as a series;

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import (
    PieChart,
    ProjectedPieChart,
    Series,  # <-- Add Series
    Reference
)
from openpyxl.chart.series import DataPoint

data = [
    ['Pie', 'Apple', 'Cherry', 'Pumpkin', 'Chocolate'],
    ['Sold', 50, 30, 10, 40]

]

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for row in data:
    ws.append(row)

pie = PieChart()
labels = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=5, max_row=1)
# data = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=2, max_col=5, max_row=2)
### Expand range for label
data = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_col=5, max_row=2)

# Add chart Series
# pie.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
series = Series(data, title_from_data=True)
pie.append(series)


pie.set_categories(labels)
pie.title = "Pies sold by category"
ws.add_chart(pie, "D1")

wb.save('pie_chart.xlsx')
```